# Multiple HDCs into one HDC to Bitblt in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, bitblt

```
void Draw(int _iPane, HDC hDC, const CRect& scrRect, BOOL bRecalc)
{
    const std::vector<Info>& drawinfos = App::General::Infos();
    std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;

    for (const auto& info : drawinfos)
    {
        futures.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, [=]()
        {
            if (auto dcPtr = ThreadSafeWinGdi::CreateCompatibleDC(hDC))
            {
                HDC threadHdc = dcPtr.get();
                CDC* threadCDC = ThreadSafeWinGdi::FromHandle(threadHdc);
                auto view = static_cast<View*>(App::GetView());

                CRect rect = view->GetViewRect();
                HBITMAP newBitmap = ThreadSafeWinGdi::CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, rect.Width(), rect.Height());
                auto oldBitmap = (HBITMAP)(threadCDC->SelectObject(newBitmap));
                auto brush = ThreadSafeWinGdi::CreateSolidBrush(view->GetBkColor(_Env().GetEllipsoid()));
                ThreadSafeWinGdi::FillRect(threadHdc, rect, brush.get());

                CManager manager;
                manager.SetEventWnd(coconutView);
                manager.SetDC(_iPane, threadHdc);
                manager.SetViewRect(_iPane, scrRect);
                manager.SetMapRect(_iPane, App::GetERManager().GetDrawMapRect(_iPane), FALSE);

// ::Polygon, ::Polyline...(thread safe ok)
                DrawInfo(manager, _iPane, info);

                ThreadSafeWinGdi::BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, rect.Width(), rect.Height(), threadHdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
                ThreadSafeWinGdi::DeleteObject(newBitmap);
            }
        }));
    }

    for (auto& future : futures)
    {
        future.wait();
    }
```

I would like to process drawing through multithreading.
After creating and drawing a `dc` for each thread, I want to draw it by `Bitblt` to `mainDc`.
However, it seems that only the `bitblt` target appears at the end.

ex) ThreadSafeWinGdi code

```
BOOL ThreadSafeWinGdi::DeleteObject(HGDIOBJ ho)
{
    static std::mutex deleteObject;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(deleteObject);

    return ::DeleteObject(ho);
}
```

Comment: What is `ThreadSafeWinGdi`?

Comment: @VladFeinstein, I add the code to the post.
I am wrapping the mfc function as a mutex.

Comment: Not a good idea, what problem are you trying to solve here? Note, windows are highly afinitized to the thread they were created in. Consequently, you should be handing the paint on the main UI thread (the one that pumps and handles that WM_PAINT message. I imagine spinning up and waiting on secondary threads in your paint handler will make it that less responsive/performant.